# Duplicate records when consuming from MS SQL database via JDBC source connector

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using a JDBC source connector to consume from a MS SQL database table.
Attaching a picture for connector configurations.[image]

I am getting duplicate records while using these configurations. Data gets populated at 11 AM , then comes at 4pm and further at 8pm, daily
While I am able to get all the records, but during these period of 11 to 4 pm ,I am getting duplicate  records (until 4 pm when new batch arrives) which arrived at 11 am .
Same situation for 4pm to 8 pm.

I am running "**timestamp** mode" query on a column **ModifiedOn** whose datatype is **datetime** and precision in **seconds**.
No *ERROR* is received in connect logs.

I believe error is due to  timestamp (precision in seconds ) column only , as connector query will poll in millisecond format.

Please , suggest a solution for this. I can't do changes in column at database level.

Comment: Anyone ever told you about copy-pasting text? Or if that's somehow impossible, a screenshot?

Comment: Hi James, can't copy-paste this, kafka servers are on company pc. Data copy/screenshot/mailing outside network are not allowed there, also can't open stack overflow there. Hope you get the struggle.

Comment: If you have that kind of security rules, then you should not be taking pictures either.

Comment: I have changed everything in there which is sensitive and irrelevant to question. If you have actually something to offer here than please share ,else no point in discussing this further.

Comment: I don't see the "db.timezone" setting.  Check that your db timezone and put that in the setting to calibrate your connector.

Comment: HI, I have added timestamap.delay/interval.ms  to get (GMT+5.30) db.timezone match ,while querying on that timestamp column.

Comment: Not sure about the particular issue, but I would suggest trying Debezium instead if you want to absolutely prevent duplication

Comment: @Nan-7 Did those changes help or were you still seeing the issue?

Comment: Hi @franzke ,still facing same issue ,db.timezone  also didn't help.